# Dashboard with builds, commits and files from GitLab

Tags: gitlab, dashboard, gitlab-ci

How do I do dashboard with information from my GitLab repo? I don't know how I get information about builds, commits and files and create dashboard with this information. Any idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitLab's API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/api) to obtain the information from GitLab. You will need to have an user account which can access a particular project. Get this user's "Private Token" from the */profile/account* page and then you can make requests for which you would get a JSON response.

### Retrieving latest commits

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [TOKEN]" \
"https://[HOST]/api/v3/projects/[PROJECT ID]/repository/commits"
```

### Retrieving latest builds

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [TOKEN]" \
"https://[HOST]/api/v3/projects/[PROJECT ID]/repository/builds"
```

These are examples using `curl`. Depending on the programming language you are going to use, you will have to make a `GET` request while setting a HTTP header (that is what `-H` in my example stands for) named `PRIVATE-TOKEN`.

Comment: @EmersonMacedo, isn't the API not providing the information you need or are you facing some other problem?